# Cannot get session value in included .php file

Tags: php, session

Iam trying to get session value `$_SESSION['LinkID']` but there is nothing in there..

in the main.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    header("location: ../index.php");
}
?>

<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Banner">
        <div id="Logo">
            <img src="../images/banner.png" width="200" height="60" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div id="Navigation">
            <?php include ("../cmd/funct/createlink.php");?>
            <?php $_SESSION['LinkID'] = GenerateLinkID();?>
            <?php include ("../modules/menu/menu.php");?> <!-- $_SESSION['LinkID'] Not Empty -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="oContent">
        <?php echo $_SESSION['LinkID']?> <!-- $_SESSION['LinkID'] Not Empty -->
        <?php include ("../cmd/funct/openpages.php");?> <!-- $_SESSION['LinkID'] EMPTY -->
        <?php echo "<br>".$_SESSION['LinkID']?> <!-- $_SESSION['LinkID'] Not Empty -->
    </div>
</div>
```

in the openpages.php (included in main.php)

```
<?php
    echo $_SESSION['LinkID']; //$_SESSION['LinkID'] Not Empty
    if (empty($_GET[$_SESSION['LinkID']])) {
        echo 'EMPTY';
    } else {
        echo 'NOT EMPTY';
            $oXo = htmlspecialchars($_GET[$_SESSION['LinkID']]);
            if ($oXo==EncryptLinkKey('encrypt', 'home')){
                include ("statistic.php");
            } elseif ($oXo==EncryptLinkKey('encrypt', 'sin')) {
                include ("mailing/in/index.php");
            } elseif ($oXo==EncryptLinkKey('encrypt', 'sout')) {
                include ("mailing/out/index.php");
            } elseif ($oXo==EncryptLinkKey('encrypt', 'srep')) {
                include ("mailing/report/index.php");
            } elseif ($oXo==EncryptLinkKey('encrypt', 'slogout')) {
                include ("../logout.php");
                header("location: ../index.php");
            }   
    }
?>
```

if i add `session_start()`in openpages.php, it will show a notice

> A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

and the result always "EMPTY"

whats wrong in openpages.php... Am i missing something?

Comment: by using `if (empty($_GET[$_SESSION['LinkID']])) {` you need to have a querystring parameter called `$_SESSION['LinkID']` - is this the case?

Comment: Incidentally, unless you are using output buffering because you have started outputting html content you would likely get an error when setting the header in `openpages.php`

Comment: @RamRaider i just want to get value in `$_SESSION['LinkID']` if empty then show nothing and if not empty it will open (include) another page. and i never get in to `elseif` condition.

Comment: try to remove $_GET[]

Comment: @SamirNabil if i remove `$_GET`, i can get in to `elseif` condition.. but include file not loaded..

Comment: your remove the `$_GET` from both locations? empty & htmlspecialchars

Comment: @SamirNabil if i remove `$_GET`, `empty` and `htmlspecialchars` from both location, the result is EMPTY with **Notice :** `Undefined index: A7Zn1yvIey4pqmh3d4j83C32qJAl5OB1L1RsL6WR87cWg08VZZZR9mC0fudxQ0aYtuGG9r1KiTdntxf4S1M1Lfz4rOC95jw2XXs53cPNFF14dezwigWo1isFZ9YY08O951a3X3h0z2VYJ1641ld1n1i35GR42Q4PWHFEvBVw6HMS3vDJe07X2rv47eh3Q9PgRoh6P672D3AW3F4fky74BXEIFLTV21YG9E6rG4O8NwLkJZ1knG4uen1db3Co034` and the code looks like this `if ($_SESSION['LinkID']) {` and  `$oXo = $_SESSION['LinkID'];` is that correct?

Comment: @SamirNabil upps.. i made a mistake, there is no Notice and the code looks like this `if ($_SESSION['LinkID']) {` and` $oXo = $_SESSION['LinkID'];` is that correct? but the result is EMPTY

Comment: yes $oXo can be also `$oXo = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['LinkID']);` and try `!isset` instead of `empty`

Answer (score 0):

At the very  top of both Files, try to establish an open session like so:

```
<?php
    // FIRST CHECK IF SESSION EXIST BEFORE STARTING IT.
    // DO THIS AT THE VERY TOP OF EACH SCRIPT THAT NEEDS ACCESS TO $_SESSION DATA
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
        session_start();
    }
```

Afterward, you can start adding  codes  that relate to `$_SESSION`

Comment: the resut still EMPTY.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your function returns nothing?

```
<?php $_SESSION['LinkID'] = GenerateLinkID();?>
```

Please write what's in this `$_SESSION['LinkID']` inside `main.php` like:

```
<?php $_SESSION['LinkID'] = GenerateLinkID();
echo $_SESSION['LinkID'];?>
```